# Firestore FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is saving the local timestamp instead of server's timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

- I have a chat app & currently I handle dates using **timeIntervalSince1970**. This is how it is stored in firestore
- Since two people can chat from two different countries, I handle this by taking the **local timestamp**, convert it to GMT timestamp & then store it in firestore
- Turns out this is bad implementation as we should never rely on device time, so I just shifted to using Firestore's **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()**
- I thought that firebase will use it's own server time (my firebase server is in US) but it seems to be storing it in the local time (I'm in India currently)
- What am I missing here? I understand that it is storing in UTC but the local time is displayed in the document. How do I store a single global time?

Here is the code:

```
func firebaseTimestampSet(){
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("dateTest").document(currentUid)
    ref.setData(["timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()])
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: This was the local time in India]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will read in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time **independent of any time zone or
> calendar**, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
> nanosecond resolution **in UTC Epoch time**.

If you see, in the Firebase console, that "the local time is displayed in the document" it is because the Firebase console uses the timezone configuration of your computer to display the Timestamp value in your local time.

---

In conclusion:

- Question: "How do I store a single global time?" Answer: "With `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, it is already the case, it is stored in UTC".
- It's up to you, in your app, to decide how to display the Timestamp values (as UTC or converted to the users' timezone).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that. I guess they should mention that in the documentation as well that in the console it shows your systems date & time

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do find it annoying that they add that UI to the field, as it becomes confusing.

Comment: I agree but once you know it it is ok and you don’t get confused like the first time ;-). If my answer helped you,please upvote it!